# Slack app using Bolt. How do I programatically get the incoming webhook url?

Tags: slack, bolt

I'm building a Slack app using Bolt  (currently hosted by Glitch). When a user adds my app to his channel, I want my app to discover the incoming webhook URL so I can send it off to another app which will post information to that URL.

I've tried (as someone suggested) subscribing to the 'member_joined_channel' event, but the event is not driven when the app is added to the channel.

Comment: Seems like you need to add bot event subscription. The documentation says : Even bot users receive this delightful event via Bot User subscription, when joining a channel.  https://api.slack.com/events/member_joined_channel

Comment: I am getting that event now (member_joined_channel), but the event payload does not contain the incoming webhook URL.

Comment: You can only get the webhooks, either from the slack app configuration page or when you create the webhook programmatically .

Comment: I partially solved the problem with the "create webhook programmatically" approach -- which is to get it from the oauth response (https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#incoming_webhooks_programmatic).   The problem is that it only works for the channel I select in the "Add App" form for "Where should SmartDraw post?".  This app needs to be added to multiple channels and needs a webhook for each of them

Comment: You cannot generate webhooks on the fly. I assume your workflow requires to create a channel & then assign a webhook to it so that some third party api can use the webhook to post to the channel. If this is the case then, instead of direct webhooks, your app needs to interact with 3rd party and then post message using slack web methods

Comment: Thank you @SuyashGaur, this is what I ended up doing.